# Add javascript to sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript

I must add a JavaScript to Sharepoint 2013.

I must add by JavaScript dropdownlist with links. How could I add a Link to dropDownList which will work at site Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can reference scripts in the masterpage of this forma:

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="custom.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />`

[Referncing a java script inside my master page will not fire](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76350/referncing-a-java-script-inside-my-master-page-will-not-fire)

Answer (score 0):

You can either add directly into the sharepoint page where sharepoint list sits using content editor webpart, or use Script editor webpart. You can also inject javascript in list view webpart using JSlink.

Comment: but I triedScript Edytor, and Content Edytor, and itdrop me a Javascript code.

Comment: When you say "it drop me a JavaScript code", you mean that you see the code in the browser? I'm sorry, but I have to ask this, did you enclose the code in <script></script> tags? Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: @cubanGuy This is a duplicate question.  His original question (see my comment below question for link) has the code he tried.